# Sync iPad & Dumbphone Contacts via Bluetooth?

Tags: ipad, applications, contacts

My Mom's main computing device is now an iPad. It's been working great for several months, but I'm trying to do what I can to get her to make use of its full capabilities.

One of the things I wanted to do was help her organize her contacts. Right now she's just using a dumb phone, but it's got Bluetooth and I'd love to find a way to transfer contacts from her iPad to the phones address book. I'm pretty sure this is a no-go with the built-in iOS functionality, but are there any apps that can do this?

Comment: What is a Dumbphone ?

Comment: @Simon [opposite of “smartphone”](https://www.google.com/search?q=dumbphone), *a.k.a.* “feature phone”. Think traditional phone with a number pad, no apps, etc.

Comment: I thought it might be that but i've never heard that term before, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

This is not likely to happen, as you need to mannualy accept a bluetooth data transfer, so it will not sync exactly, what you are doing is basicly sending a contact card to the phone.

Source - my Mom and her really dumbphone.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [BitPim](http://www.bitpim.org/).

It allows you to connect via USB to the filesystem of many dumb phones and extract address, calendar, etc., data therein.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for something that only requires iOS.

Comment: Some carriers allow you to back up your dumb phone address book and then edit the data through a web interface. My Verizon phone years ago had this feature.  Wouldn't be a true sync but it would be better than t9 data entry.